# Find out position of subview in relation to view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, subview

I have a view which contains multiple subviews. Each of them contain subviews, and so on. A few layers down is a subview that I have as an object. I want to find out it's frame position inside a view a few layers up. How can i find this out?

Answer (score 2):

I thought you meant the (x,y) position of the view with respect to the superview. If that's the case you can use `UIView`'s method `– convertPoint:toView:`

```
[yourView convertPoint:yourView.frame.origin toView:yourSuperView];
```

Hope this helps!